# Migrating Mac over home network

Tags: macos, migration

I am trying to migrate all settings, apps, and data from MacBook Yosemite 10.10.5 to MacBook Catalina 10.15.2 over a home network. I have computer initial setup on the same network with different computer names but the same user name.

I disabled firewall on both and launched migration assistant on both; "To another Mac" on the "Michael's Mac"Book and "From Mac" on the "Tamara's MacBook". Right away I see that "Tamara's" sees "Michael's" but "Michael's" doesn't see "Tamara's". Soon after I attempt to start the transfer the "Tamara's" reports the failure to communicate with "Michael's".

The odd thing, up to that moment "Tamara's" sees "Michael's"m and I choose "Michael's" to migrate from, but after pressing "continue" the error reads "Michael's MacBook" cannot be reached. Ensure both Macs are on and cnnected to the same network.", followed by a suggestion to turn off the firewall. But the firewall is off, and they are on the same network, and "Tamara's" does see "Michael's"...

What could be the problem here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be to time machine backup the machine you want to migrate, and simply restore it to the new machine, then run OS updates.